# XML node innerText is loaded twice in dataGridView cell value using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I try to add some value to a `dataGridView` cell using C#. I have a column for each week day (Monday-Sunday). To do that I use this code:

```
xdoc.Load(Properties.Settings.Default.TaskPlannerXmlPath);

foreach (XmlNode task in xdoc.SelectNodes("/tasks/task"))
{
    string date = task["taskDate"].InnerText;
    string day = date.Substring(0, date.IndexOf(","));

    for (int w = 0; w < timeTableGridView.Columns.Count; w++)
    {
        string colName = timeTableGridView.Columns[w].Name;

        if (colName == day)
        {
            timeTableGridView.Rows.AddNew();

            for (int ew = 0; ew < timeTableGridView.Rows.Count; ew++)
            {
                timeTableGridView.Rows[ew].Cells[colName].Value = task["taskName"].InnerText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I read an XML file for getting the `InnerText`. My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tasks>
  <task>
    <taskName>test shutdown</taskName>
    <taskDate>Friday, 2. May 2014</taskDate>
    <taskTime>00:00</taskTime>
    <taskType>Shutdown</taskType>
  </task>

  <task>
    <taskName>test start</taskName>
    <taskDate>Sunday, 4. May 2014</taskDate>
    <taskTime>12:00</taskTime>
    <taskType>Wake Up</taskType>
  </task>
</tasks>
```

So now it should add in column "Friday" the text "test shutdown" and in column "Sunday" it should add "test start". But it doesn't. It adds "test shutdown" in column "Friday" and then it adds "test start" twice in column "Sunday".

I just don't get rid of it.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your loop

```
for (int w = 0; w < timeTableGridView.Columns.Count; w++)
```

iterates over every day of the week. If one of them is the same as the one you got from xml (which will always happen), you're adding a new row (what would that represent?) and then FOR EVERY ROW existing your setting up the task in a given day.

I think you may have some problems with understanding what and how would you represent in your datagridview. Right now data is redundant, since row with 7 columns will always use only 1 of them, while all others will be empty.

**EDIT:**

The thing is: you can't represent calendar in a datagridview this way (it's doable, but it'd be too difficult at this point). Assuming you want to do some kind of scheduler, your columns should be

Task Name, Date, Time and Type

and then each task from xml should be loaded as a row.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Is there a better way to add a new row? I use `Rows.AddNew()` because else I don't have any rows so my for loop won't work anymore

Comment: But why would  you want to use that for loop? Use the last entry. What are you trying to achieve? What is your row supposed to mean? The whole table makes no sense. Also, windforms datagridview row's property does not contain `AddNew()` method.

Comment: I use Telerik `RadGridView` that's why I can use `AddNew()` method. In winForm it doesn't exist. I have to get the data from my XML nodes in my dataGridView. What else should I use instead of the loop for every row? I never worked with dataGridView before.

Comment: I'm guessing `AddNew` should return a reference to the new row, so you can edit it, instead of doing a lookup in a loop. So `var newRow = timeTableGridView.Rows.AddNew();` and then `newRow.Cells[colName].Value = task["taskName"].InnerText`. Also, check out my edit to the answer.

Comment: My man. Works fine. I think I'll have a closer look at dataGridView to understand the whole thing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Per your example, by the time you get to Sunday, you have already created two rows via calls to `timeTableGridView.Rows.AddNew` (one for Monday, and another one for Sunday).  The following loop operates on the "sunday" column, but iterates twice because there are two rows:

```
for (int ew = 0; ew < timeTableGridView.Rows.Count; ew++)
```

Comment: Hmm okay, sounds logical. But I have to add a new row at the beginning. Else I won't have any rows and then my for loop won't work because there's no row. Or is there another way?